# Package installation on nixOS retrieves "Unsupported distro detected. Some dependencies may not be present" but indicates no error. Was it installed?

Tags: installation, package, nixos

I am running NixOS. This is my [config](https://github.com/pdelfino/my-nixos-config/blob/main/configuration.nix) file.

I am trying to install this software: [Enclave](https://enclave.io/). Thus, I am following this [starting guide](https://docs.enclave.io/getting-started/installation/).

Usually, I change my config file, do a `sudo nixos-rebuild switch`, and re-start the PC. However, apparently, there is not an official package of Enclave on NixOS official [package list](https://search.nixos.org/packages?channel=21.11&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=enclave).

Since NixOS is not Ubuntu/Debian/Raspbian, CentOS/RHEL/Fedora, Amazon Linux, OpenSUSE/SLES, I am following the instructions for *Others*.

It says:

> Arch Linux
>
> Requires at least Arch Linux 2020.08.01.
>
> ```
> Install Enclave using our quick-start script
> ```
>
> bash <(curl -Ss https://install.enclave.io/setup.sh)
>
> Provide your Quick Start Key to complete the installation

I thought running this command would **not even start an execution**. Out of curiosity, I did on the *shell* buffer of Emacs:

```lisp
[pedro@system:~]$ bash <(curl -Ss https://install.enclave.io/setup.sh)
[+] Checking/installing dependencies.
[-] Unsupported distro detected. Some dependencies may not be present.
[sudo] password for pedro: 
[+] Installing enclave-2021.12.06.838.
[+] Starting Enclave service.
```

It seems to work somewhat.

According to the documentation, `sudo enclave` is supposed to run the program. However, if I try that, I get:

```sh
[pedro@system:~]$ sudo enclave
sudo: enclave: command not found
```

If the installation failed, isn't NixOS supposed to indicate that?
If the installation succeeded, why I can't run the program?
Is there a way to check what **really** happened?
Is there something I could try?

Thanks

Comment: You could try their docker instructions.
The script definitely did not do anything useful and you may want to clean up the files it left behind in `/usr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since NixOS is not Ubuntu/Debian/Raspbian, CentOS/RHEL/Fedora, Amazon Linux, OpenSUSE/SLES, I am following the instructions for Others.

But nixos is not Arch either. under 'others' there is only Arch Linux available. But i doubt nixos structure (pkg-mngr,dependencies,atomicity etc.) is anything near or like Arch.

I would say the installation definitely failed, but maybe nixos has 'installed' some simple dependencies. you should find and purge them. Enclave simply does not support nixos at current state.

Delete the following:
/usr/bin/enclave

if nixos has also systemd:

/usr/lib/systemd/system/enclave.service

/etc/systemd/system/enclave

Comment: Thanks. How do I find them?

Comment: I've edited the post and added the directories you may find something..

Comment: Thanks. There was `/usr/bin/enclave` and `/usr/lib/systemd/system/enclave.service` . But there was no `/etc/systemd/system/enclave`.

Comment: `/etc/systemd/system` is for modified files , but since you haven't done anything in this regard there is no enclave unit file in there >ok